# Adding a WCF service into a subfolder

Tags: wcf

I have created a new wcf4 web application and added a new wcf service.
I created a subfolder and moved the service created into the subfolder.

e.g.

```
ROOT
ROOT/Business/V1/BusinessV1.svc
```

I have deployed the service onto my IIS7 enviroment however I keep getting this error

> The type
>   'MyNameSpace.WebWCF.Business.V1',
>   provided as the Service attribute
>   value in the ServiceHost directive, or
>   provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations
>   could not be found.

My service file looks like this

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MyNameSpace.WebWCF.BusinessV1" CodeBehind="BusinessV1.svc.cs" %>
```

The code behind looks like

```
namespace MyNameSpace.WebWCF
{
  public class BusinessV1 : IBusinessV1
  {
  }
}
```

My contract looks like

```
namespace MyNameSpace.WebWCF
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IBusinessV1
}
```

Finally my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="MyNameSpace.WebWCF.Business_v1">
         <endpoint 
             address="http://mydomain.com/Business/v1/BusinessV1.svc" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="" 
             contract="MyNameSpace.WebWCF/IBusinessV1" 
             listenUri="/" isSystemEndpoint="true" />
      </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong? its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one thing is: your service name isn't consistent.

In your service implementation class, you have:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.WebWCF
{
  public class BusinessV1
```

and in your `*.svc` file, you have the same qualified name:

```
Service="MyNameSpace.WebWCF.BusinessV1"
```

but in your `web.config`, you use:

```
<service name="MyNameSpace.WebWCF.Business_v1">
```

Your service implementation is the one that defines the service name - fully qualified with the namespace: `MyNameSpace.WebWCF.BusinessV1`

So you need to use this fully qualified name - and **exactly** that - in your `*.svc` file (OK!) and your `web.config`:

```
<service name="MyNameSpace.WebWCF.BusinessV1">
```

Use `MyNameSpace.WebWCF.BusinessV1` insstead of `MyNameSpace.WebWCF.Business_v1`.

If that name doesn't match, the WCF runtime won't find the config you've specified and will fall back to system defaults

Answer (score 0):

Two questions which hopfeully may help:

1st: Are you sure the contract still corresponds to the webservice after moving?

and/or

2nd: Have you updated the webservices (from the context menu of the web service entry in the project list; atm. i have no VS to be more specific).

Comment: Hi Ofi. I am not sure how to test the 1st point. Locally it works ok however after deploying it fails. 
Using the wcftest client fails also